# LF> os.system(filePath) alternative

Tags: python, opencv, pdf, os.system

I'm having an issue due to the fact that in my Python code `os.system(filePath)` will execute but the code stops until I manually close the window of the opened PDF file.

I would like to open a PDF file use openCV to capture my screen thus capturing the image of the file. This becomes an issue if the code does not run without me closing the window...

CODE:

```
import numpy as np
import shutil,os, cv2, SendKeys, win32com.client

#While our In File has stuff in it
while(os.listdir(pathForInFile)!=[]):
    for subdir, dirs, inFile in os.walk(pathForInFile):
        for fileName in inFile:
            filePath= subdir+os.sep+fileName

            os.system(filePath)

            print "THIS WILL RUN NOT UNTIL I CLOSE FILE"

            shell.SendKeys('{DOWN}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this solution both on Windows 8.1 (tested in a virtual machine):

```
import os
os.system('start path_to_my_filename.pdf')
print("You do not need to close the opened PDF file to run and see this")
```

and Ubuntu (14.04.4 LTS):

```
import os
# f = /home/begueradj/Desktop/metasploitBible.pdf'
os.system('xdg-open path_to_my_filename.pdf')
print("You do not need to close the opened PDF file to run and see this")
```

Comment: Thanks Bill! It is running now and I can continue to debug and get things to keep moving along. Just wondering why does it work with 'start'? Also, it's not displaying the pdf like it once was and I added time.sleep(10) to delay it for a bit...

Comment: `start` opens the PDF file with the default application running in your operating system so I wonder what makes you think *it's not displaying the pdf like it once was* In my virtual and host machine I do not see a any difference though.  For why it works with `start`, I can not give you an explanation as `start` is not a Python command but it belongs to your operating system and how it reacts. Why did you add `sleep()`?

Comment: When I had it originally to the `os.system(filePath)` the pdf file would be opened using the default application. So it would be opened for me to view and the code would not run until I closed it. I replaced the code with `os.system('start'+filePath)` in order to grab the location and the correct file. Once I did this the computer went on a frenzy due to the while loop. So I figured I pause it for a second since I need to see the pdf on my desktop in order for my openCV code to capture a certain section of my screen... since i can't convert pdf to .jpeg or .png(I'm on WIN10 D:)

Comment: I have fixed the bug today I just simply needed to add a " " thanks for the help